# JSON to PHP, then foreach?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, pdo

I send a valid JSON string to my PHP page from jQueryscript:

```
var data = '{
 "data":[
  {
   "id":"12",
   "checked":"true"
  },{
   "id":"4",
   "checked":"false"
  },{
   "id":"33",
   "checked":"false"
  }
 ]
}';


$.post ("page.php", { data_input:data }, function (data) {
 // code
});
```

Once I get the data in my PHP page, I parse it with the `json_decode` method, and then try to use it in a `foreach` statement created for a `PDO` query:

```
<?php

$data_input = json_decode ($_REQUEST['data_input'], true);

$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET user_enabled = :checked WHERE node_prop_id = :id";
$stmt = $dns->prepare ($sql);

foreach ($data_input as $data) {
 $ok = $stmt->execute ($data);
 $num = $stmt->rowCount ();
} 
if ($ok) return 1;
else return 0;

?>
```

This returns me the error:

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../page.php on line XX

Can I find a way to use my JSON data in the `foreach` statement?

Comment: Have you checked that the $_REQUEST['data'] string doesn't contain escape characters? If it does (and they often do), I bet json_decode can't decode it, and returns null. You could use stripslashes($string) to get rid of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

```
<?php

// I've changed $data to $json for more clarity
$json = json_decode (stripslashes ($_REQUEST['json_string']), true); // added stripslashes method for more debug, but i think it still works without
$json = $json["data"]; // this was the problem

$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET user_enabled = :checked WHERE node_prop_id = :id";
$stmt = $dns->prepare ($sql);

foreach ($json as $value) {
    $ok = $stmt->execute ($value);
    $num = $stmt->rowCount ();
} 
if ($ok) return 1;
else return 0;

?>
```

Comment: Yesterday one user has gave the right answer, but has removed it

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure json_decode runs through by checking [`json_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)
- Make sure you check that `$data_input` is an array. The result of a json_decode() operation is [**not necessarily always an array**](https://www.php.net/json_decode):

> Return value
>
> Returns the value encoded in json  in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null (case-insensitive) are returned as TRUE, FALSE  and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json  cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

though in your case, it should be. I am betting on a decoding error.

> **Edit:** Victor Nicollet spotted the actual error. It's still good to use json_last_error and do some more checks!

Comment: strange, I have json library but not the method json_last_error return a missing function error

Comment: Can you do a test output of $_REQUEST["data_input"] using print_r and post the results?

Answer (score 1):

You're treating `$_REQUEST['data']` as if it were a JSON string, which is not always the case (I could send a request with an invalid value if I wanted to), nor will it always be a JSON string representing an array or dictionary. You would need to check beforehand, and react accordingly if it isn't.

Now, for your actual bug. You wrote:

```
 $.post (page.php, { data_input:data }, function (data) {
   // code
 });
```

This would be an error, since `page.php` is not quoted. But even assuming that it is in your actual code, server-side the data would be stored in `$_POST['data_input']`, not `$_POST['data']`.

Comment: sorry, they was only copy/paste errors (I've semplified the code), I've fixed them